# Which xdebug version is compatible with php7 and SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: debian, xdebug, php-7

Do You know any of xdebug version which is compatible with `php7` and `SimpleXMLElement`? In `php5` there was `xdebug-2.3.2`. It was the only version which i know that worked with SimpleXMLElement and it work properly with it. Now i have got `xdebug-2.5.0RC1` installed and it causes crash when i try to open SimpleXMLElement in debug console.

Comment: What exactly does not work (if you use latest stable **2.4.1**). would be good to see some very simple code (so it can be easily used for local testing (I can check in PhpStorm)).

Comment: If i try to look into SimpleSMLElement it shows that there is nothing in it's nodes.

Comment: From https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30656 comments:  https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1272 -- consider checking there